# Make undeclared variable return undefined instead of throwing ReferenceError

Tags: javascript

I am making a scripting API that accepts a user script and "compiles" a function from it.
It binds the function to the proper this, injects the variables into its scope and executes it when requested.

The user can have some variables defined in the scripting model, these get injected into the scope of the function when executed.

This all works as expected.
If the user uses a variable that is injected into the resulting script function he gets the value.
The problem comes when he uses a variable that is not injected, that is the variable is not (yet) defined in the scripting model.
In this case executing the resulting function will throw a ReferenceError.

The client asked me to not throw ReferenceError but to return undefined instead.

It makes little sense to me to use variables that are not declared, but I'm still wondering if there is some way to do this.

Take this as an example:

User provides the following script:

```
print(someothervariable)
print(somevariable)
```

print is a function that is part of my scripting API.
The scripting model contains the following variables:
(the user does this)

```
somevariable with value "1"
```

I "compile" the following function for this user script:

```
function f(print, somevariable) {
    print(someothervariable)
    print(somevariable)
}
```

When I execute this function "someothervariable" does not exist and throws ReferenceError.
The user wants this to return undefined instead.

So he expectes this script to print the following:

```
undefined
1
```

Is there a way to achieve this considering I am creating the outer part of the function, and the user only the inner body of the function?

Comment: *It makes little sense to me to use variables that are not declared* <-- It makes little send to the JS runtime as well, that's why it throws an error. You could wrap the code with `try/catch`.  You could also just access the input arguments via the `arguments` property.

Comment: Try/catch does not help to print undefined for a non declared variable (and continue executing the script). Btw I am using try/catch around the script to show the errors, this is not shown in the question to make it simple. This is how I present the errors to the user. But their request was to not throw in this case, but just return undefined. I get that this problem is coming from how the JS engine works, but I'm wondering if there is a way around it.

Comment: *Try/catch does not help to print undefined for a non declared variable (and continue executing the script).* <-- Uh, yes it does. https://codepen.io/S__MAR/pen/ZEPYMGz

Comment: The semantics you are asking for are not possible in JavaScript. Your "compiler" will need to detect all variable references and pass them in, regardless of whether there is an assignment or they are part of your model. You can use an AST library like esprima, acorn, espree, Babel, and others. The syntax will be different, but any of them should let you parse the script and identify any variable usage. You could then dynamically pass in the variables to your function.

Comment: Ask the user to write their code in the form of property accesses, like `context.print(context.someothervariable)` (or do that in your compilation).

Comment: @ScottMarcus i think you misunderstood me. try/catch does not continue the execution of the script as soon an error is thrown, therefore won't print anything at all since it will throw ReferenceError and go into the catch, and this is explicitely what I don't want to happen. I need the variable access to not throw ReferenceError  and return undefined so that i can call functions with it in some way instead.

Comment: @Bergi this is what i'm was doing initially, but it is boilerplate all around, so they asked to get rid of it, which is when we got to this question in the first place.

Comment: @rfestag If you find a way to find out variable accesses that have no variable declarations (in babel for example) that could be an answer. I can remove from those the ones that are defined in my model and inject dummy names for the ones missing and initialize then with undefined. But unfortunately I think there is no way to do that, at least I have not found it.